# Qt android debugger adb error Address already in use

Tags: android, qt, gdb, adb

Im trying to debug android application using Qt Creator and getting the following error:

```
W ActivityThread: Application org.qtproject.example.tid_trains_android10 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
adb: error: cannot bind listener: Address already in use
17:47:24: Failed to forward JDB debugging ports.
```

When I try to see the open ports Im not seeing anything listening at 8100

I searched the net but found nothing.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: The term "ActivityThread" is common for Android apps. This indicates that this error message might be generated on the Android device, so it is port 8100 on the phone, not on your computer. I would recommend to reboot the phone.

Comment: I tried to reboot the phone, but the problem still exist.

Comment: I am not familiar with Qt creator but I would assume that the port is hard coded somewhere in it but on your phone the port is already used. May be there is an option to select a different port or you could ask the Qt creator developers.